# Click event for multiple figures

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling

I want to extract the values of a graph by clicking on them in the figure, while also adding a marker at this point/delete the old marker. I manged to do this for a single figure, however in my practice case I have multiple figures.

Whe I have multiple figes, the clicking event only properly works for the most recent figure. Clicking in the other figures will print out the values of the last figure/add marker in the last figure.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib qt


# Function to get the closest actual value
def find_nearest(array,value):
    idx = (np.abs(array-value)).argmin()
    return array[idx]

# Function to ectract the value from the graph by clicking
def onclick(event,x,y,fig):
    if event.inaxes is not None:
        ix = find_nearest(x,event.xdata )
        iy = y[np.where(x==ix)[0][0]]

        text = (f'x = {ix},   y = {iy}\n')

        ax1 = fig.get_axes()[0]
        # Update the plots
        if len(ax1.get_lines()) > 1: 
            delete = ax1.get_lines()[-1]
            delete.remove()
        ax1.plot([ix],[iy],marker="x",color="b")
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        print(text)

# test case
x = np.arange(0,10,1)
y1 = x
y2 = x**2
y3 = x**3

f1 = [x,y1]
f2 = [x,y2]
f3 = [x,y3]
functions = [f1,f2,f3]

for f in functions:
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1)
    ax1.plot(f[0],f[1])
    #plt.show()
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lambda event: onclick(event,f[0],f[1],fig))
```

If anyone knows hot to fix it, that would be highly appreciated.

I already tried to put fig, ax1 and cid into dictionaries and adjust the function parameters however this did not change anything.

Funnily enough, if I do the plotting and calling of the function without a loop, but 3 times individually, at least the retrieving of the coordinates part of the function works. Only the adding/deleting of the marker does not work then...

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224342/matplotlib-pick-events-across-multiple-figures#comment56238105_34224342), however I didn't quite understand the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to write a code for multiple plots but I do not think it is possible. So, I have come up with an idea - when you run the code, all the plots are shown:

[image: Subplots]

Then you can click one of them. For example, if you click on the second plot, it will open like this,

[image]

You can click on this plot and it will show the marker and output the coords in the terminal. If you want to access the other plots, just close this window. The 3 plots will appear. Then you can select for example, the third one. Then if you want to terminate the code, just close the original window(the one with all 3 subplots)

Here is my code:

```
# Import modules
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# Test data
x = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 1.0)
y1 = x
y2 = x**2
y3 = x**3
# 
x_data = [x, x, x]
y_data = [y1, y2, y3]
#
colors = ["red", "blue", "green"]  # color to identify which data is viewed
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

while True:

     # Define the figure and axes of each subplot
     # Documentation https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html
     fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, len(x_data), figsize=(16,16))

     # Axis added when viewing one subplot
     ax_added = None

     # Plot the data in each plot
     for i in range(len(x_data)):
          axs[i].plot(x_data[i], y_data[i], color=colors[i])
     # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

     # Variable that stores which subplot is selected
     ax_selected_index = None
     ax_selected_index_copy = None

     # Boolean that keeps track if only one plot is displayed
     selected = False

     # Function to retrieve which subplot has been clicked
     def onClick1(event):
          global axs, ax_selected_index, ax_selected_index_copy

          # Iterate through each plot
          for i in range(len(axs)):

               # Check which plot has been clicked
               # Answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047846/determine-button-clicked-subplot
               if (event.inaxes == axs[i]):
                    
                    ax_selected_index = i
                    ax_selected_index_copy = i

                    return
     # ----- #

     # Define the coordinates of the mouse when clicked
     mouse_pos_click = [None, None]

     # Function to get mouse coordinates
     def onClick2(event):
          global mouse_pos_click

          # Saves x and y coordinates of mouse
          mouse_pos_click = [event.xdata, event.ydata]
     # ----- #

     def on_close(event):
          global selected

          # Close on first window
          if not selected:
               exit()
     # ----- #

     def animate(i):
          global axs, ax_selected_index, selected, mouse_pos_click, ax_selected_index_copy, ax_added

          # Exit if the user close the first window
          fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', on_close)

          # Retrieve the clicked mouse coordinates
          # If mouse is click --> run onClick1 event
          plt.connect('button_press_event', onClick1)

          # Check whether user has clicked a subplot
          if ax_selected_index != None:
               
               for ax in axs:
                    # Hide X and Y axes label marks
                    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelbottom=False)
                    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelleft=False)

                    # Hide X and Y axes tick marks
                    ax.set_xticks([])
                    ax.set_yticks([])

               # Add another plot "on top" of axs
               ax_added = fig.add_subplot()
               # Plot the required graph
               ax_added.plot(x_data[ax_selected_index], y_data[ax_selected_index], color=colors[ax_selected_index]) 

               # Reset the selected index 
               ax_selected_index = None

               # Update the boolean
               selected = True

          if selected:

               # Retrieve the coordinates of the mouse
               plt.connect('button_press_event', onClick2)

               # Check if user has clicked
               if mouse_pos_click[0] != None:

                    # Find the closest actual value
                    indx = (np.abs(x_data[ax_selected_index_copy]-mouse_pos_click[0])).argmin()

                    # Clear the plot
                    ax_added.clear()
                    # Plot the line
                    ax_added.plot(x_data[ax_selected_index_copy], y_data[ax_selected_index_copy], color=colors[ax_selected_index_copy])
                    # Scatter the point
                    ax_added.scatter(x_data[ax_selected_index_copy][indx], y_data[ax_selected_index_copy][indx], color="black", s=50)

                    # Reset the mouse position
                    mouse_pos_click = [None, None]
                    
                    # Output the coordinates
                    print(f"Figure : {ax_selected_index_copy}")
                    print(f"x = {x_data[ax_selected_index_copy][indx]}, y = {y_data[ax_selected_index_copy][indx]}")
                    print("\n")
          

     animation = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=50)

     # Display the plot
     plt.show()
     # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
```

I hope this helps you !

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. Somewhow, the problem lies in the loop... I don't know exactly why, but when I put the figures into a dictionary and then executed the click events individually, it worked. But as soon, as I try to do it via a loop, it does not work. If anyone knwos the reason for this strange behavior, I would be glad to get an explanation.

However, how I solved the problem in the end was by adding a function, which executes the click event. By doing so, I can use a loop again.

```
def access_click_event(figure,x,y):
    figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lambda event: onclick(event,x,y,figure))


figures = {}
for n,f in enumerate(functions):
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1)
    figures[n] = fig
    ax1.plot(f[0],f[1])
    access_click_event(figures[n],f[0],f[1])
```